# gridview column span not working

Tags: asp.net, gridview, html-table, multiple-columns

I have gridview which takes datatable from sql server. When the datatable has no rows i have written a function to bind the gridview from a separate source which adding a new row to the gridview also merging all columns and displaying error message "No Result found" but this is not working the all columns are displaying as it is. The function for binding empty grid is given below

```
   private void ShowNoResultFound(DataTable source, GridView gv, bool footerStatus)
   {
       source.Rows.Add(source.NewRow());
       gv.DataSource = source;

       gv.ShowFooter = footerStatus;

       int columnsCount = gv.Columns.Count;
       gv.DataBind();
       gv.Rows[0].Cells.Clear();
       gv.Rows[0].Cells.Add(new TableCell());
       gv.Rows[0].Cells[0].ColumnSpan = columnsCount;


       gv.Rows[0].Cells[0].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
       gv.Rows[0].Cells[0].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
       gv.Rows[0].Cells[0].Font.Bold = true;

       gv.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = "NO RESULT FOUND!";

   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set EmptyDataText="No Result Found!!!" Property of Grdi View